# How can you carry out Outlook Interop Actions (such as reading emails) within C# .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, outlook, .net-6.0, office-interop, .net-4.8

I am having great difficulty attempting to read emails out of my Default Inbox using Interop in C# .NET 6.0.

I have an application that currently utilizes **Interop** to read the users most recent emails from their Outlook, this application utilizes **.NET Framework 4.8** and does not compile with any errors, but as a part of a a application I am currently developing, I am required to use the new **.NET 6.0** SDK instead of .NET Framework.

The Code block I have taken from the **.NET Framework 4.8** application is below:
`

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

private Outlook.Items ReturnOutlookEmails()
{
    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
    var outlookVersionString = oApp.Version;

    Debug.WriteLine(oApp.Session);

    Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

    Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(
        Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    //Get the Items collection in the Inbox folder.
    Outlook.Items emails = inbox.Items;

    return emails;
}
```

The error that is being thrown is of type "System.InvalidCastException", but if you look below that, it seems the real issue relates to an issue importing a COM component.

> *"System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).'"*

The COM Component it is failing to import is the Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library, I know this due to the fact that when I attempt to import the Library VIA the Dependencies Manager within the Project it does not correctly import, and shows the COM IID.

[Image of Microsoft Outlook COM Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXPTQ.png)

I have tried many different ways to fix this error, but it seems whatever I try fails. I have attempted install the **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll** from NuGet, but this gives me a different issue, and stops this Method from running at all.

The Error found when using the package from NuGet can be found below:

> *System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified.'*

I am completely stumped at this point, and I am struggling to find a way to fix this issue, if anyone knows a way to fix this, or somehow workaround this issue, such as the creation of a **.NET Standard** Class Library that integrates with my **.NET 6.0** application, that would be awesome!

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: Is it an 32-bits vs 64-bits problem perhaps? Your app being 64-bits while the Outlook automation dlls only want to be loaded in a 32-bits process?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to process new incomming mails. If your mailbox is office365 and if you have access to azure logic apps, that would save you trouble, you can create a trigger on incomming mails with a few clicks and do logic after that like calling an api or store data.